# unserialize() php function not converting when I put folder address instead URL

Tags: php, wordpress, post-meta

I am inserting post meta into database using wordpress, the field I want to insert is video url but sometimes I insert video folder address from my windows.
the way they are inserted is like this:

```
s:162:"a:1:
    {i:0;a:5:
        {s:4:"type";
        s:1:"2";s:4:"lang";
        s:3:"364";s:7:"quality";
        s:3:"365";
        s:4:"link";
        s:41:"https://www.youtube.com/embed/j49fPpRiNgc";
        s:4:"date";
        s:4:"2021";}}";
s:306:
    "a:2:{i:0;a:5:
        {s:4:"type";
        s:1:"2";
        s:4:"lang";
        s:3:"364";
        s:7:"quality";
        s:3:"366";
        s:4:"link";
        s:27:"D:\films\242\Pompeii.mkv";
        s:4:"date";s:9:"30/6/2021";}}";
```

The first one is video URL and the second one is video address. So when I want to show them first I need to convert to array using unserialize() function but for video address, its not working.

```
<?php
    $trmovieslinks = unserialize(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'trmovieslink', true)); 
    var_dump($trmovieslinks);   
?>
```

for video address it returns nothing.

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't use JSON encoding instead?

Comment: There is no reason I just did not use, let me try that once. tnx

Comment: Makes no difference on that.